# Android - Superuser request dialog, remember choice options are disabled

Tags: android, android-source, superuser

I am using a rooted Android device (6.1.1, API 23) and an Android Studio developed/installed APK that executes su commands:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes("adb shell " + "\n");
os.flush();
os.writeBytes(commandString + "\n");
os.flush();
os.close();
```

Each execution triggers a dialog asking to grant superuser permissions for the application.  However, all of the remember choice options are all disabled.  The only option available is to grant superuser privileges "This time only".

Any ideas on the cause/solution?

Note, the system image is built from AOSP + drivers.

Comment: Are you want to grant root permission to this app permanently ? You can install `SuperSu` that manages root access to applications . In SuperSu you can grant root permission to a specific app in multiple ways : one time or permanently. Download SuperSu zip file then go to recovery of your phone and install it.

Comment: I've tried SuperSu, it definitely works.  I was hoping to use the feature built-into Android/AOSP.  There is a dialog option to grant superuser permissions  permanently, but it is disabled.  I'm not sure why.  Another option is to find the location in the source and force enable the option.  I'm building my own image from AOSP source.